# Formatting and Bullets in a TextBox in iOS5

Tags: ios5, webview, formatting, xcode4.3

Does anyone know how to insert bullets and do some formatting in a textbox, maybe in a webview (as shown in the print screen below) in iOS 5, XCode 4.3?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the `UITextView` manually add dots and newlines, for example:

```
NSArray  *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Stack",@"Overflow",nil];
NSMutableString *formattedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init ];
for (NSString *item in items) [formattedString appendFormat:@"\u2022 %@\n", item];
theTextViewName.text = formattedString;
```

For the `UIWebView` create an unordered `HTML` list, for example:

```
NSArray  *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Stack",@"Overflow",nil];
NSMutableString *theSource = [[NSMutableString alloc] init ];
[theSource appendFormat:@"<ul>"];
for (NSString *item in items) [theSource appendFormat:@"<li>%@</li>", item];
[theSource appendFormat:@"</ul>"];
[theWebView loadHTMLString:theSource baseURL:nil];
```

Both result into the following list:

> - Stack
> - Overflow