# How to add Bullet in the newline text in Webview

Tags: iphone

I need to know how to add bullets in the web view as we can see in the MSWord Doc files.
I am trying to find out this thing but could not find any success.
If anyone can help then please help me out from this....
Here is my code

```
        function moveCursorToNextLine(x, y, newX, newY) {

    var label3= iOS.UI.createLabel({
                                        text:'speaks and \nsolution world oneself has ',
                                        color:'black',
                                        height:'auto',
                                        width:'auto',
                                        left:232,
                                        font:{fontSize:14},
                                        //textAlign:'center',
                                        top:480
                                        });
    view.add(label3);

    }
```

I am waiting for your valuable help

Comment: Here you have find the Help full Code and try your code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798930/iphone-bullet-point-list

Comment: @ Vikas S Rajput  Wel my requirement is different from that one.if there is anything else then please share

Comment: @ Abhishek Rajput Review this ans may be helped you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365941/formatting-and-bullets-in-a-textbox-in-ios5

Comment: @Vikas S Rajput Dude i need to use javascript as if i used that code then my web view become non editable and that code gimme the static bullets and i need the dynamic bullets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this  :

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand(\"insertunorderedlist\")"];
```